# Select average entries per day into table

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok I have looked at multiple entries in stackoverflow for this but cant seem to quite work them for me.

I have a table called email_Archive

It contains every email sent by every user.

Columns in Db are:

```
id
created
username
message
recipient
```

Challenge: I am trying to get the average amount of emails sent by a select list of users per day for the last month. (created covers YYYY-MM-DD:MM:ss)

select List of users:

```
A:
f:
g:
h:
i:
n:
q:
r:
```

The only info I want to return is userid and the average count per day for the last month only. and yes on some days that will be 0 but I need to show that 0 for that day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
Select id as userid, Count(*)
From MessagesTable 
Where created > Dateadd(month, -1, GETDATE()) and id in (userids you want)
group by Cast(created as Date)
```

If you want it into a seperate table you can do either:

```
Select id as userid, Count(*)
into TargetTableName
From MessagesTable 
Where created > Dateadd(month, -1, GETDATE()) and id in (userids you want)
group by Cast(created as Date)
```

or

```
Insert into TargetTableName
Select id as userid, Count(*)
From MessagesTable 
Where created > Dateadd(month, -1, GETDATE()) and id in (userids you want)
group by Cast(created as Date)
```

Comment: @JohnFP . . . This code will not run in MySQL (the tag on the question), yet you have accepted the answer.  Confusing.